# Remove enclosing tag with preg_replace/php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to remove some custom tags from my html string. The string loogs like:

```
some html code
<para>
    <embed view="embed" [...some more attributes...]>[...]</embed>
</para>
more code here...
```

This block of code can occur multiple times in one page (comes from a cms backend).
I need to remove the "para" and "/para" tag so that only the "embed" tag will remain. I tried several preg_replaces, but I could not find a working solution until now.

Can someone give me some help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Also this element will never have attributes?

Comment: PHP [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) could maybe be useful. Too bad there isn't an opposite function.

Comment: @FirstOne ... if he _just_ wants to remove the `<para>` tags then he'd have to add every single other HTML elements to the list of allowed tags with `strip_tags()` ... if that is the case, it's not exactly practical.

Comment: @CD001 I didn't answer, though. I left a comment and who knows, maybe someone visiting find it useful in the future.

Comment: @chris85: I tried somethink like
    preg_replace('~<para><embed[^>]*?/></para>~', $replace, $htmlString);
The "para" will never have more attributes.

Comment: That would fail because `><` never occurs in your mark up. You can put `\s*` in between and it would be closer. A parser would really be your best bet here though since you want to maintain the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple code like this:

```
$tags = array("<para>", "</para>");
$string = "<para>
                <embed view=\"embed\" [...some more attributes...]>[...]</embed>
           </para>";
echo str_replace($tags, "", $string);
```

**[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/gLB7oi)**

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work because (as written in my question) there can be more html code both before and after that block where the "para" tags must remain.

Comment: @Philip, check **[this sample](https://regex101.com/r/NoFscU/1)**. Is this what you want?

Comment: Great, that's what I'am looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below to solve your problems.

```
<?php
$string = "<para><embed view='embed'>[...]</embed></para>";
$new  = strip_tags($string, '<para>'); 
echo $new;
?>
```

Tested locally. Working like a charm at my localhost.

Comment: Kind of ignoring the fact that the example states that there is HTML code both before and after that block - so you've just stripped all the tags from that too... not to mention that that strips everything **except** the `<para>` tags - the exact opposite of what's requested.

Comment: No it results as he need. I had tested it locally.

Comment: Then you misunderstood what was needed I'm afraid - if you compare your result (`<para>[...]</para>`) to the demo on the accepted answer (`<embed view="embed" [...some more attributes...]>[...]</embed>`).